# Listbox show unique number and does not show listed if specific column has zero(0) value vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

'My code is here Userform1 initialize for listbox1

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, countD As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, boolDupl As Boolean
  Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1") 
  LastRow = sh.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  ReDim arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To LastRow)  
  arr = sh.range("A2:B" & LastRow).value 
  k = 1 
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    boolDupl = False  
    For j = 1 To k    'iterate between the arrFin elements in order to check for duplicates
        If arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) = arrFin(1, j) & arrFin(2, j) Then
              boolDupl = True: Exit For 
        End If
    Next j
    If Not boolDupl Then 
        arrFin(1, k) = arr(i, 1): arrFin(2, k) = arr(i, 2)
        k = k + 1       
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To k - 1)    
  With Me.ListBox1
        .clear
        .ColumnCount = False
        .ColumnCount = 2 
        .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin) 
        .ColumnWidths = "50;500"
        .TopIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

At first I want listbox1 show the Unique List by sheet1 column (A) then column (C) all the value is zero(0) for code:1101 and it will be not listed by listbox1. So Listbox1 show unique list only code:1102 & 1103.

Please follow my attach picture for details. Kindly help me

[Populate Listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRXiZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is getting unique values based on both column A and B.

If you only want unique values based on column A and want to exclude values where column C is 0 try the following code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, countD As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, boolDupl As Boolean

    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim arrFin(1 To 1, 1 To LastRow)

    arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & LastRow).Value

    k = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 3) <> 0 Then
            boolDupl = False
            For j = 1 To k    'iterate between the arrFin elements in order to check for duplicates
                If arr(i, 1) = arrFin(1, j) Then
                    boolDupl = True: Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If Not boolDupl Then
                arrFin(1, k) = arr(i, 1)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 1, 1 To k - 1)
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = False
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
        .ColumnWidths = "50"
        .TopIndex = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Note, there are other methods to do this that don't involve multiple loops, e.g. a dictionary, evaluating a formula in the code.

### Evaluation Example

Here's an example of doing it by evaluating a formula, it's specifically for Office365.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim sh As Worksheet, arrFin As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long

    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arrFin = Evaluate("SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A" & LastRow & ", C2:C" & LastRow & "<>0)))")
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = False
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .List = arrFin
        .ColumnWidths = "50"
        .TopIndex = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```